# Multiple update target ids with Ajax.ActionLink ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

Is there a way to specify multiple update target ids with Ajax.ActionLink so that I can render a set of partial views on callback?

The problem that I'm seeing is that Ajax.ActionLink only provides one target id for me to update, but what I need is to update multiple regions of the page with different data after an ajax call.

Any help on this would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can check this link: http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/08/23/asp-net-mvc-with-jquery-superload.aspx

I had the same problem and it helps me to solve it

Comment: i used this, worked, with minor changes to get it to work in VB. still, it's a messy solution. The mvc team need to be smacked in the head for resorting us to this, why can't they just make a framework that WORKS and does common, basic every-day things as one would expect?

Comment: @Erx_VB.NExT.Coder: the cleaner solution is to used Json result, you can update any part of the page you want using javascript on this result

Comment: @Erx_VB.NExT.Coder I know this was some time ago, but you should look into Apache Wicket, if you do not have to stay with asp.net Framework. Wicket uses Java for the server side code though (only minor difference).

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't. You could, however, write code which does this yourself. You would need to:

1. Partition the returned HTML into different "areas" which you will apply to different parts of the page. You could do this on the controller (perhaps by rendering multiple actions and storing a list of the HTML fragments returned) or in JavaScript.
2. Write JavaScript code to take the returned HTML, iterate the targets you'd like to update, and apply the appropriate HTML fragment to each. The code would look something like the code below.
3. Don't use the Ajax form HTML helper. Instead, render a standard form and submit it via JavaScript.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "/action/controller",
    success: function(data) {
        var key;
        for (key in data) {
            $("#" + key).html(data[key]);
        }
    }
 });
```

This presumes that the action you call will return an object where the property names are the IDs of the elements to update, and the property values are the HTML fragments as strings.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but if you use the same solution as @Gregoire pointed to (http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/08/23/asp-net-mvc-with-jquery-superload.aspx) for the server side you can pass multiple ids in AjaxOptions

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Link", "Action", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "id1, #id2" })
```

the MVC framework will automatically prepend the '#' to `id1` in this case. You will then need to modify `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`'s asyncOnSuccess function around line #45 to look like this:

```
mode = (element.getAttribute("data-ajax-mode") || "").toUpperCase();
$(element.getAttribute("data-ajax-update")).each(function (i, update) {
    var top,
        html = $("#" + update.id, data).html();

    switch (mode) {
    case "BEFORE":
        top = update.firstChild;
        $("<div />").html(html).contents().each(function () {
            update.insertBefore(this, top);
        });
        break;
    case "AFTER":
        $("<div />").html(html).contents().each(function () {
            update.appendChild(this);
        });
        break;
    default:
        $(update).html(html);
        break;
    }
});
```

The Javascript is just using the same id that's passed to grab only that content and replace the same id with that same content. This also works for Ajax.BeginForm(). Make sense?