# Update more than one view in a MVC3 ajax ActionResult

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I'm approaching to mvc3 developing but I'm not sure if what I want to do is the correct way to proceed...

Let's say I have a CONTACTLIST where i show some contacts and in a right tablecolumn i have an object that makes the SUM to show me the number of contacts stored.

I whant to make an (ajax) inline add that add a partialview of "ContactCreate" at the bottom of my listview, and when the contact has been saved, i would like to update the listview AND the sumview.

I have to start from a Ajax.Actionlink, like:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("New Contact", "InlineContactCreate", "Contact", new AjaxOptions
            {
                UpdateTargetId = "ReferentList",
                HttpMethod = "GET",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            })
```

that calls

```
  public ActionResult InlineContactCreate(Contact c)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                   db.Contact.Add(c);
                   db.savechanges();

                   .
                   .
                   .
                   return PartialView("ContactList",)
            }
```

but then i have to update 2 views. How can i call 2 actions for 2 different ?
thanks for any help.

Comment: See this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088257/multiple-update-target-ids-with-ajax-actionlink-asp-net-mvc