# How to change more than one ID by Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, actionlink

I have this ActionLink:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" + ", "Plus", "Review",
                 new { cardid = item.CardId, userid = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId },
                 new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "plus-" + @item.CardId},
                 new { @class = "plus", data_theme = "c", data_icon = "true" })
```

It is possible to change by UpdateTargetId more than only one (the first) element with ID = "plus-" + @item.CardId on the Page ?

Because I have in the Page div's with the same ID more than only one. The same Card could be shown 1-3 times.

Thanks.

David

Comment: What do you mean `I have in the Page div's with the same ID more than only one`... Valid HTML does not allow duplicate IDs!

Comment: This option is called `Id` because it really uses `Id`, which is supposed to be unique on the page. If this is not your case - you might want to fix that in first place. As for multiple targets update - update them manually, as [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088257/multiple-update-target-ids-with-ajax-actionlink-asp-net-mvc) suggests